# How to create a custom page on WSO2 API Manager?

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager, custom-pages

There is a home page which can be enable at defaultTheme.js
Is there a way to create a custom page like About us

Comment: what's the version?

Comment: its WSO2 API-M v3.0.0

Answer (score 1):

we can override any existing UI elements by [1]. By this method we can add any custom page.

[1] - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/learn/consume-api/customizations/customizing-the-developer-portal/advanced-customization/